# Gulp script doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, gulp

I followed steps from a couple of blogs, installed `npm` and `gulp`, did everything  the blogs said, and yet when I need to import `GulpScript.js` to my project, there's no script available. What is the problem? How do I enable `GulpScript`? I have a `json` file with dependencies like `gulp`, `gulp-sass` etc and have run `npm i`

Comment: Gulpscript? Do you mean gulpfile.js? Gulp recognizes only the latter as an actual file that it can run.Also, did you follow this? https://gulpjs.com/

Comment: @Jabberwocky yep, I meant that. I didn't followed that specific guide, but I installed gulp-cli, I will try this other lines

Comment: That's the official guide of gulp. Nothing else works, I tell you from experience. Main steps: install npm globally, gulp globally, npm locally gulp locally. Gulp runs gulpfile.js and reads from that.

Answer (score 0):

The thing I did, maybe most ridiculous thing, but... I couldn't get gulpfile.js so I made simple .js file and name it gulpfile.js, run it and it worked...